# ¿Cómo se libera la memoria de una matriz dinámica?

Tags: c

Buenas, he estado buscando la manera de construir una matriz de forma dinámica y parece que la forma es:

```
int main(){
    int **mat;
    int filas = 2, columnas = 3;   /*Supongamos esos valores*/

    mat = (int **)malloc(filas * sizeof(int *));

    for(i = 0; i < columnas; i++)
        mat[i] = (int *)malloc(columnas * sizeof(int));
```

Sin embargo, no encuentro como se libera la memoria asignada a la matriz. ¿Simplemente se hace `free(mat)` o hay que hacer `free(mat[i])` para cada fila y después `free(mat)`?

Comment: unicamente `free(mat)`. Recuerda que free solo debe usarse con bloques asignados a través de malloc (o equivalentes). `mat[i]` no fue asignado con malloc así que te dará error si tratas de hacer `free(mat[i])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes usar `free()` para liberar la memoria de cada uno de los elementos que has creado con `malloc`. Eso sería `mat` y los diferentes `mat[i]` dentro del bucle.

Pero **lo que realmente importa es el orden en el que lo realices**. Si fueran `malloc` independientes, podrías hacer `free` sin importar el orden; pero en el código de la matriz, tienes un `malloc` que reserva espacio para una "lista de punteros" (`mat`) a otras zonas de memoria reservadas también con `malloc` (`mat[i]`). Existe una dependencia entre ellas. Si hicieras un `free` del puntero inicial (`mat`) entonces las otras reservas que has hecho con `malloc` quedarían huérfanas y sin manera de acceder a ellas o liberarlas. Es por eso que, en este caso, debes liberar la memoria en orden inverso al que se reservó: primero los `mat[i]` dentro de un bucle y finalmente `mat`.

Algo como esto:

```
for(i = 0; i < columnas; i++)
    free(mat[i]);

free(mat);
```